# How to fix TypeScript error: property 'current' does not exist in type "x"?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Got that ts error when using a ref: property 'current' does not exist in type '{ (options?: ScrollToOptions | undefined): void; (x: number, y: number): void; }'.

Parent

```
  const scroll = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  return (
    <div className="chat-page">
      <ChatTopBar />
      <ChatMessages forwardedRef={scroll} />
      <ChatInputBar scroll={scroll} />
    </div>
  );
```

Child

```
export const ChatInputBar = ({ scroll }: HTMLDivElement) => {

  const handleSendMessage = async () => {
    scroll.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  };
```

Comment: `HTMLDivElement` is the wrong type for your props. You're probably at something like `{ scroll: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement> }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your props correctly. Typescript currently thinks `ChatInputBar` is destructuring the `scroll` function of a div element rather than a jsx attribute named `scroll`

```
type Props = {
  scroll: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>
}

export const ChatInputBar = ({ scroll }: Props) => {
...
}
```